# Save error: Constructor not defined: [Sample11.EventData].<Constructor>(Id, Datetime, Datetime, String)

Tags: apex, rest, apexrest, compile-error, sqlserver

I'm trying to expose user related events using REST API but I get the error at line 33. Why?

**Error Line:**

```
EventData eveData = new EventData(eve.Id,eve.StartDateTime,eve.EndDateTime,eve.subject);
```

**Error Message:**

> Save error: Constructor not defined: [Sample11.EventData].(Id, Datetime, Datetime, String)

**Complete Code**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/calendardetails/*')
global with sharing class Sample11 {
    @HTTPGet
    global static void getCalendarDetails(){
    Set<ID> userIDS = new Set<ID>();
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String OwnerId = ((String)req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)).trim();

    RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
    if (response == null) {
    response = new RestResponse();
    RestContext.response = response;
    }
    try {
    if(validUserID(OwnerId)){
        EventData eventData = retrieveEvent(OwnerId);
        response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(eventData));
        response.statusCode = 200;
    } else {
        response.statusCode = 404;
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getStackTraceString());
    response.statusCode = 500;
    } 
 }

 static EventData retrieveEvent(String OwnerId){
        List<Event> eveList = [Select Id,startdatetime,enddatetime, Subject from Event where OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        if(!eveList.isEmpty()){
             Event eve = eveList.get(0);
             //ERROR ON BELOW LINE
             EventData eveData = new EventData(eve.Id,eve.StartDateTime,eve.EndDateTime,eve.subject);
             return eveData;
        }
        return null;

 }

    static boolean validUserID(String OwnerId){
        boolean valid = true; 
        String userId = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(userId);
        Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(OwnerId);

        if (!myMatcher.matches()){ 
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid; 
    }
    public class EventData{

        public Map<String, String> even = new Map<String,String>();     
        public EventData(String Id, String startdatetime, String enddatetime,String Subject){

            even.put('id', Id);
            even.put('startdatetime', startdatetime);
            even.put('enddatetime', enddatetime);
            even.put('Subject', Subject);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should **[edit]** your post with any additional information you wish to add, rather than burying it in the comments on one of the posted answers. Also, please **include any error messages verbatim**.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor accepts `startDatetime` and `endDatetime` as `String` parameters, but you are trying to pass in `Datetime` values. You have two options:

1. Change the parameter types to `Datetime`.
2. Pass in the values as `String` data.

I would prefer option 1. You can still put them into the map as strings in a variety of ways, the simplest of which is to call `Datetime.format()`. Or you can just change `even` to be a `Map<String, Object>`, depending on how you are consuming this data.

```
public MyClass
{
    public Map<String, String> data { get; private set; }
    public MyClass(String Id, Datetime startDt, Datetime endDt, String subject)
    {
        String startDatetime = startDt.format();
        String endDatetime = endDt.format();
        data = new Map<String, String>
        {
            'id' => id, 'subject' => subject,
            'startdatetime' => startDatetime,
            'enddatetime' => endDatetime,
        };
    }
}
```